# C++: multiline string literal with concatenation?

Tags: c++, string, variables, multiline

How can I define a multiline raw string literal that can be concatenated with other variables? The following does not compile:

```
#define theValue 1000

static std::string str = R"(

foo )" + theValue + R"( bar

)";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::to_string` should help you out with this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

```
#define theValue 1000

static std::string str = R"(

foo )" + std::to_string(theValue) + R"( bar

)";
```

In the general case, you need `string`s or something that can be implicitly converted into a `string` in order to use `std::string`'s concatenation operator.